# Web Config Multiple Rewrite Rule

Tags: angularjs, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, s3-rewrite-rules

I am working on angularjs project. this project contains two index pages.
I need to redirect to index1.html for the url domain/Admin/* or redirect to index2.html. i have the following rewrite rule in web config, this always redirect to index2.html.

```
    <rule name="Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/Admin$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index1.html" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Rule2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index2.html" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Whats wrong with this rule.please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Hey did you get the solution for this?

Comment: Run in to same issue. Did you get a solution for this?